# Antlr4, Target C++, Generating parser code from grammar "DynScope" from docs generates "error(33)", what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, antlr4

Target: c++
Generating parser code with ANTLR 4.13.0
Expected behavior: does not generate any error .
Actual behavior: generates the
"error(33):  missing code generation template SetNonLocalAttrHeader"

The DynScope grammar from the doc triggers the error. (from "Actions and Attributes" chapter, exactly as it is in it.)

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=Java DynScope.g4` works

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=PHP DynScope.g4` works

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript DynScope.g4` works

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp DynScope.g4` does not work and generate the error(33).

I've isolated the issue.
Here is a simplified version of the grammar that triggers the same error:

```
grammar DynScope;
 
prog: block ;
 
block locals [int myInt = 0;]
    : '{' decl* '}' 
;

decl: 
  'int' INT {$block::myInt += 1;} ';'
;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

if i just comment the `{$block::myInt+=1;} ';'`, no errors is triggered.
like that:

```
grammar DynScope;
 
prog: block ;
 
block locals [int myInt = 0;]
    : '{' decl* '}' 
;

decl: 
  'int' INT // {$block::myInt += 1;} ';' 
;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

replacing `{$block::myInt += 1;}` by `{((BlockContext*)$ctx->parent)->myInt +=1 ;}` seems to work properly, but i can't be 100% sure.

i'd like the correct syntax to work properly.
how ?

Comment: The action code you wrote is correct: you are explicitly navigating via C++ code from a `decl` node to the `block` node (parent of `decl`) in the partially constructed parse tree. But, be warned! Action code makes your grammar brittle and not portable to other targets. Also, it assumes the tree has been partially constructed at the time you want to evaluate the action. As a general rule, place your attributes in the parser object, not the tree. Also, actions that aren't directly associated with a semantic predicate `{ ... }?` should not be executed in the parse.

Comment: @kaby76 i agree. that's why i am not satisfied with the "hack" patch code.
Also i edited to add context, and remove ambiguity on what build is. i talk about generating parser code. My issue is, C++ seems to be the only target that does not generate the parser code.

Comment: Yes, it seems that for the other targets, the attribute `$block::myInt` passes code gen of the Antlr tool and generates  the right code. If you can please open a Github Issue in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues.

Comment: @kaby76 Already done. issue #4372 ;)